# "triggered him" vs "triggered something in him"

Tags: word-usage

> I asked him this question that I thought seemed pretty harmless, but apparently **it triggered something in him**, 'cause all of a sudden he was crying.
>
> I asked him this question that I thought seemed pretty harmless, but apparently **it triggered him**, 'cause all of a sudden his was crying.

Are both correct? Is there any difference between the two phrases?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? I had never heard _to trigger someone_, but I googled _trigger definition_ and learned that the word can also be used in that way.

Answer (score 1):

As many movements that promote mental health awareness are starting to become more mainstream in society, tolerance towards people suffering from mental illness is increasing and some terminology related to psychology is now understood by more people than before. In psychology, a ***trigger*** is something that elicits memories of a traumatic experience. For someone who has [post traumatic stress disorder (PTSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder), for example, this can make them very distressed.

This word has been adapted into a verb ***to trigger [someone]***, meaning *to cause a negative emotional reaction [in someone]*. (see NOTE at bottom)

Here is an example: when soldiers go to war, they may witness very disturbing events, such as people losing their lives, and memories of these events can cause great distress. Therefore, if a soldier goes to watch a war movie, they may become distressed because some scenes may cause these memories to come back. The scenes *trigger* the soldier. This is where the second sentence comes from.

For the first sentence, I see the word *trigger* as meaning *initiate something*, which is similar but isn't as specific as the meaning in the second sentence.

---

NOTE: The verb *to trigger [someone]* can also be used in a negative way, usually when someone does not take someone's emotional reaction to something seriously. This sense is frequently used in political commentary on the internet. For example, if Person 1 makes a statement that Person 2 does not like or is offended by, someone may mockingly say that "*Person 2 is **triggered***!" This serves to make fun of Person 2's reaction to Person 1's statement.